# GridView: how to Pass encoded data on click of hyperlink field

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I try to pass an encoded URL string in hyperlink field of GridView like below:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Customer" DataTextField="Customer" DataNavigateUrlFields="Customer"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString= "Changes.aspx?customer={0}" SortExpression="Customer"
    NavigateUrl="~/Client.aspx" />
```

I get this error:

> Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event.  System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField does not have a DataBinding event

Is there any way we can pass an encoded string in a hyperlink field?

Alternate approach:

Additionally, is there any way we can read special characters in the query string? Can I read until some specific special character if I use this?

```
Request.QueryString["customer"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Snippet taken from the msdn link I posted above that will show you what you need .. Follow this example and it should work for you.. change the Field Binding values to match your case..
Example pasted from this link [MSDN - HyperLinkField.DataNavigateUrlFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx)

```
 <h3>HyperLinkField Example</h3>

      <!-- Populate the Columns collection declaratively. -->
      <!-- The UnitPrice field values are bound to the         -->
      <!-- captions of the hyperlinks in the HyperLinkField    -->
      <!-- field column, formatted as currency. The ProductID  -->
      <!-- field values are bound to the navigate URLs of the  -->
      <!-- hyperlinks. However, instead of being the actual    -->
      <!-- URL values, the product ID is passed to the linked  -->
      <!-- page as a parameter in the URL specified by the     -->
      <!-- DataNavigateUrlFormatString property.               -->
      <asp:gridview id="OrdersGridView" 
        datasourceid="OrdersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false"
        runat="server">

        <columns>

          <asp:boundfield datafield="OrderID" 
            headertext="Order ID"/>
          <asp:boundfield datafield="ProductID" 
            headertext="Product ID"/>
          <asp:hyperlinkfield datatextfield="UnitPrice"
            datatextformatstring="{0:c}"
            datanavigateurlfields="ProductID"
            datanavigateurlformatstring="~\details.aspx?ProductID={0}"          
            headertext="Price"
            target="_blank" />
          <asp:boundfield datafield="Quantity" 
            headertext="Quantity"/>

        </columns>

      </asp:gridview>

      <!-- This example uses Microsoft SQL Server and connects -->
      <!-- to the Northwind sample database.                   -->
      <asp:sqldatasource id="OrdersSqlDataSource"  
        selectcommand="SELECT [OrderID], [ProductID], [UnitPrice], [Quantity] FROM [Order Details]"
        connectionstring="server=localhost;database=northwind;integrated security=SSPI"
        runat="server">
      </asp:sqldatasource>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but It is not sending the value as encoded value.

Comment: I found the solution for this. You need to convert hyperlink field to Templete Field and then Pass the navigationURL as I am passing below like:                                               NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Customer", "Clients.aspx?customer="  + Server.UrlEncode(Eval("Customer").ToString())) %>'